# ¿Hay alguna forma de mostrar las propiedades de un JSON en el orden en que vienen declaradas en la clase?

Tags: php, json

Estoy trabajando con varios JSON que antes se construían manualmente, concantenado y luego usando `json_encode`.

Ahora he creado modelos que representan a esos JSON, creo instancias de cada clase y luego creo el JSON usando esas instancias.

Mi problema es que así el JSON no se muestra de forma ordenada, es decir, las propiedades no se muestran en el orden en que son declaradas en la clase. Yo necesito ese orden para hacer una comparación visual entre la forma antigua y la nueva, verificando que están todas las propiedades, pero esto se dificulta al venir las propiedades en cualquier orden.

Por ejemplo, tengo esta clase:

```
namespace App\Models;

class Officium extends \App\Models\TypusBreviarium implements \JsonSerializable{

    private MetaLiturgia $metaLiturgia;
    private ?SanctusLH $santo;
    private Invitatorium $invitatorio;
    private OfficiumLectionis $oficioLecturas;
    private TeDeum $teDeum;
    private string $metaInfo="";

    public function __construct
    (
        MetaLiturgia $metaLiturgia,
        ?SanctusLH $sanctus,
        Invitatorium $invitatorium,
        Hymnus $hymnus,
        Psalmodia $psalmodia,
        OfficiumLectionis $officiumLectionis,
        TeDeum $teDeum,
        LHOratio $oratio
    )
    {
        parent::__construct
        (
            hymnus:$hymnus,
            psalmodia:$psalmodia,
            oratio:$oratio
        );
        $this->santo=$sanctus;
        $this->invitatorio=$invitatorium;
        $this->oficioLecturas=$officiumLectionis;
        $this->teDeum=$teDeum;
    }
    public function jsonSerialize():mixed{
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }

}
```

El JSON se muestra correctamente, pero yo esperaba que las propiedades del JSON aparecerían tal y como se definen en la clase, es decir:

- `metaLiturgia`
- `santo`
- `invitatorio`
- `oficioLecturas`
- `teDeum`
- `metaInfo`

En cambio, las propiedades aparecen sin ningún orden definido:

```
{
   "himno":{
      "texto":"Primicias son del sol de su Palabra..."
   },
   "oracion":{
      "texto":"Protege, Señor,~con amor continuo a tu familia,..."
   },
   "salmodia":{
      "salmos":[
         {
            "orden":"1",
            "antifona":"El árbol de la vida es tu cruz, oh Señor.",
            "salmo":"Dichoso el hombre,_que no sigue el consejo de los impíos,...",
            "ref":"Salmo 1",
            "intro":"Felices los que,~poniendo su esperanza en la cruz,~se sumergieron en las aguas del bautismo.",
            "tema":"Los dos caminos del hombre",
            "parte":0
         },
         {
            "orden":"2",
            "antifona":"Yo mismo he establecido a mi Rey en Sión, mi monte santo.",
            "salmo":"¿Por qué se amotinan las naciones,...",
            "ref":"Salmo 2",
            "intro":"Verdaderamente se aliaron~contra tu santo siervo Jesús,~tu Ungido.~(Hch 4, 27)",
            "tema":"El Mesías, rey vencedor",
            "parte":0
         },
         {
            "orden":"3",
            "antifona":"Tú, Señor, eres mi escudo y mantienes alta mi cabeza.",
            "salmo":"Señor, cuántos son mis enemigos,....",
            "ref":"Salmo 3",
            "intro":"Durmió el Señor el sueño de la muerte~y resucitó del sepulcro~porque el Padre fue su ayuda.~(S. Ireneo)",
            "tema":"Confianza en medio de la angustia",
            "parte":0
         }
      ],
      "tipo":0
   },
   "santo":{
      "nombre":"",
      "vida":""
   },
   "invitatorio":{
      "antifona":"Venid, aclamemos al Señor, demos vítores a la roca que nos salva. Aleluya.",
      "id":1
   },
   "oficioLecturas":{
      "responsorio":"La palabra de Cristo habite ...",
      "biblica":{
         "libro":"Del libro del Génesis",
         "capitulo":"39, 1-23",
         "texto":"<p>En aquellos días, cuando bajaron a José a Egipto...",
         "versoInicial":"",
         "versoFinal":"",
         "tema":"José en Egipto",
         "theOrder":1,
         "responsorium":{
            "texto":"Hijo mío, ...",
            "forma":1,
            "ref":"Ga 6, 2; 5, 13"
         }
      },
      "patristica":{
         "padre":"San Clemente I, papa",
         "obra":"Carta a los Corintios",
         "fuente":"62-63: Funk 1, 141-143",
         "tema":"Mantened la concordia en la caridad y en la paz",
         "texto":"<p>Os hemos escrito, hermanos, con suficiente amplitud ...</p>",
         "responsorio":{
            "texto":"Ayudaos mutuamente a llevar vuestras cargas,...",
            "forma":1,
            "ref":"Ga 6, 2; 5, 13"
         }
      }
   },
   "teDeum":{
      "status":true
   },
   "metaInfo":""
}
```

¿Alguien sabe si existe una forma de ordenar este JSON en el orden en que las propiedades se definen en el POJO? ¿Alguien sabe qué reglas sigue PHP para ordenar el JSON del modo en que lo hace?

Este es el código que genera el JSON:

#### Controlador

```
    $service = match($options['endPoint']) {
            "mixtus","officium","laudes","tertiam", "sextam","nonam",
            "vesperas","completorium"
            =>
                new \App\Domain\Service\Liturgia\BreviariumService(
                    new \App\Domain\Infrastructure\Repository\Liturgia\BreviariumRepository(
                    new \App\Domain\Infrastructure\Mapper\Liturgia\PdoBreviariumMapper()),$options
                ),

// ...

        View::renderJson($service->getData());
```

### Vista

```
public static function renderJson($content)
{
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP/1.0
    header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
    echo $content;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Básicamente depende de la visibilidad de las propiedades y su inicialización; las más visibles primero. Peculiarmente en php8 -hasta donde recuerdo- hay una regla adicional con declaraciones de tipo y su inicialización.

Comment: Si tu script depende del orden en que existen las claves en un array (propiedades de una clase) entonces tu sistema no esta siendo eficiente ni escalable.

Comment: Esto: _comparación visual entre la forma antigua y la nueva, verificando que están todas las propiedades_ es innecesario ... lo que necesitas evaluar es que los array contengan la misma estructura, sin importar el orden....

Comment: la unica forma de re-ordenar un array/json es que tengas un patter para esa estructura y tengas un metodo para ordenamiento... lo cual vuelvo y repito es innecesario.

Comment: a lo mejor puedas encontrar alguna libreria de tercero que se encargue de hacer lo que indicas pero no existe algo asi nativamente ...

Comment: creo que puedes tener un acercamiento con reflection pero no estoy seguro de que cumpla tu objetivo, asique no me atrebo a dejar esa respuesta a tu pregunta, pero te la dejo como comentario: https://onlinephp.io/c/131ee

Comment: obviamente tendras que trabajar por tu cuenta la parte del JSON

Comment: me confirmas aqui en un comentario si te sirve...

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover el orden es requerido solamente para comparar visualmente el JSON antiguo con el nuevo, nada más. Es una medida de urgencia en la migración del código consumido por una API para lanzarlo a producción.

Comment: @A.Cedano y lo que te pasee  el link externo no te Funciona???

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover no lo he probado en realidad. Creo que el uso de Reflection es más costoso. La respuesta de Yussef me pareció más ligera y adecuada para lo que estoy necesitando en este caso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El orden que sigue es la misma que la declaración de variables, pero primero los de la clase padre y luego la clase hija Para cambiar el orden puede "setear a mano" la función `jsonSerialize`

```
    public function jsonSerialize(){
        return [
          'metaLiturgia' => $this->metaLiturgia,
          'santo' => $this->santo,
          'invitatorio' => $this->invitatorio,
          'oficioLecturas' => $this->oficioLecturas,
          'teDeum' => $this->teDeum,
          'metaInfo' => $this->metaInfo
          ];
    }
```

---

Ejemplo:

Supongamos tenemos el siguiente código:

```js
class ClasePadre {

    public $Propiedad_Padre;
    public function __construct($Propiedad_Padre)
    {
        $this->Propiedad_Padre=$Propiedad_Padre;
    }
}
class ClaseHija extends ClasePadre implements JsonSerializable {

    private $Propiedad2;
    private $Propiedad1;


    public function __construct($Propiedad2, $Propiedad_Padre,$Propiedad1)
    {
        parent::__construct($Propiedad_Padre);

        $this->Propiedad2=$Propiedad2;
        $this->Propiedad1=$Propiedad1;
    }
    public function jsonSerialize(){
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }

}
```

Esto imprime el siguiente JSON

```
{"Propiedad_Padre":"valor2","Propiedad2":"valor1","Propiedad1":"valor3"}
```

Primero las propiedades de la clase padre, y luego la hija en el orden declarado.

Ahora queremos que imprima `$Propiedad1`, `$Propiedad2` y `$Propiedad_Padre` (en este orden)

Hacemos:

```
    public function jsonSerialize(){
        return [
          'Propiedad1' => $this->Propiedad1,
          'Propiedad2' => $this->Propiedad2,
          'Propiedad_Padre' => $this->Propiedad_Padre
          ];
    }
```

E imprime:

```
{"Propiedad1":"valor3","Propiedad2":"valor1","Propiedad_Padre":"valor2"}
```

Comment: Intentando esto me da problemas el objeto `MetaLiturgia`: *`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Typed property App\Models\Officium::$metaLiturgia must not be accessed before initialization in `* Dicho objeto tiene su método `jsonSerialize()` e implementa `JsonSerializable`. No entiendo de dónde viene el error.

Comment: Diría que se debe a que `$metaLiturgia` nunca fue inicializada y por ende no esta definida (eg: `undefined != null`). Proba pre-definirla así: `private ?MetaLiturgia $metaLiturgia = null;`

Comment: Era eso justamente, no estaba inicializando la propiedad en el constructor. Ahora sí se ve todo ordenado. Gracias.