# ¿En PHP hay alguna forma de anotar atributos personalizados en una clase para usarla con JsonSerializable?

Tags: php, json, php8, serialización

Tengo una clase para convertirla a JSON implementando `JsonSerializable`. Pero en el JSON yo quiero los nombres de propiedad personalizados sin verme obligado a cambiarlos en la clase, esto por motivos de compatibilidad entre varias versiones de una API.

Supongamos esta clase:

```
namespace App\Models;

class Sanctus implements \JsonSerializable
{
    private int $mensis;
    private int $dies;
    #[JsonSerialize('nombre')]
    private string $nomen;
    private string $martyrologyum;
    private string $vita;
    private string $fons;

    public function __construct
    (
        int $mensis,
        int $dies,
        string $nomen,
        string $martyrologyum,
        string $vita,
        string $fons
    )
    {
        $this->mensis=$mensis;
        $this->dies=$dies;
        $this->nomen=$nomen;
        $this->martyrologyum=$martyrologyum;
        $this->vita=$vita;
        $this->fons=$fons;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize():mixed
    {
        $reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($this);
        $data=[];
        //recorremos las propiedades
        foreach ($reflectionClass->getProperties() as $r) 
        {
            //preguntamos por el atributo "JsonSerialize" a cada propiedad
            $attr = $r->getAttributes("JsonSerialize")[0] ?? null;
    
            if($attr!=null && count($attr->getArguments())> 0)
            {
                //si existe el atributo y tiene un argumento (ej: 'nombre'), seteamos el array asociativo con ese key
                $data[$attr->getArguments()[0]] = $r->getValue($this);
            }
            else
            {
                //de lo contrario seteamos con el nombre de la propiedad
                $data[$r->getName()] = $r->getValue($this);
            }
    
        }
        return $data;
    }   
}
```

Siguiendo [lo explicado aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.attributes.overview.php#127899) he agregado esta anotación a la propiedad `$nomem`:

```
    #[JsonSerialize('nombre')]
    private string $nomen;
```

La idea es que cuando el JSON se renderice, aparezca con una propiedad `nombre` en lugar de `nomen`, pero eso no ocurre, aparece siempre `nomen`.

¿Alguien conoce un modo de anotación para cambiar el nombre de las propiedades de la clase sin cambiar el nombre de las mismas?

Comment: Ejecuté en un terminal el ejemplo señalado y el vardump refleja correctamente el nuevo nombre de la propiedad $myValue señalado por el atributo a 'foobar'

Comment: La idea tras el ejemplo es implementar la clase AttributeBasedJsonSerializer en ese caso con el método extract() que mediante Reflection analiza cada uno de los atributos marcados en la clase que deseas serializar y sus propiedades

Comment: Suena mas para implementar un [*Adaptador*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptador_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o)).

Comment: me habias dicho que no usarias reflection .... jummm

Comment: no estoy muy seguro pero deberia ser: `$attr = $r->getAttributes(JsonName::class)[0] ?? null;` hay te voy a dejar mi respuesta con la implementación ...

Answer (score 0):

Esta respuesta es una version adaptada de la anterior que te habia comentado en esta otra publicacion:

[¿Hay alguna forma de mostrar las propiedades de un JSON en el orden en que vienen declaradas en la clase?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/611619/hay-alguna-forma-de-mostrar-las-propiedades-de-un-json-en-el-orden-en-que-viene#comment1078033_611619)

En esta caso lo que se busca es implementar correctamente la obtencion del atributo de la propiedad (pero en php la logica no siempre es la que esperamos y se llaman arguments).

Nota: solo es valido para php8 o superior el ejemplo lo he ejecutado aqui:

https://onlinephp.io/c/6c4f6

***Este es el Codigo de ejemplo:***

```
<?php

class ClasePadre {
    
    #[JsonName('prop1padre_renombrada')]
    public $xyZ_Propiedad;
    
    protected $propiedadPadre1;
    
    #[JsonName('prop2padre_renombrada')]
    public $propiedadPadre2;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->propiedadPadre = "Valor de propiedad en la clase padre";
    }

    public function obtenerPropiedadPadre() {
        return $this->propiedadPadre;
    }
}

class MiClase extends ClasePadre {
    #[JsonName('prop1renombrada')]
    private $propiedad1;
    private $propiedad2;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(); // Llamada al constructor de la clase padre
        $this->propiedad1 = "Valor de propiedad1";
        $this->propiedad2 = "Valor de propiedad2";
    }

    public function obtenerArray() {
        $properties = array_merge(
            get_object_vars($this),
            get_object_vars($this->obtenerPadre())
        );

        $className = get_class($this);
        $reflection = new ReflectionClass($className);
        $propertyNames = array_map(
            function ($property) {
                return $property->name;
            },
            $reflection->getProperties()
        );

        $orderedProperties = array_intersect($propertyNames, array_keys($properties));

        $orderedArray = [];
        foreach ($orderedProperties as $property) {
            $propertyName = $property;

            // Verificar si la propiedad tiene el atributo JsonName
            $attr = $reflection->getProperty($property)->getAttributes(JsonName::class);
            if (!empty($attr)) {
                $propertyName = $attr[0]->getArguments()[0];
            }

            $orderedArray[$propertyName] = $properties[$property];
        }

        return $orderedArray;
    }

    private function obtenerPadre() {
        return $this; // En este caso, simplemente retornamos la instancia actual
    }
}

// Ejemplo de uso
$miObjeto = new MiClase();
$miArrayOrdenado = $miObjeto->obtenerArray();

// Imprimir el array ordenado
print_r($miArrayOrdenado);
```

***output:***

```
Array
(
    [prop1renombrada] => Valor de propiedad1
    [propiedad2] => Valor de propiedad2
    [prop1padre_renombrada] => 
    [propiedadPadre1] => 
    [prop2padre_renombrada] => 
)
```

**Nota:** en la documentacion no hay mucho para la lectura: [introducir la descripción del vínculo aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionattribute.getarguments.php), Practicamente lo he encontrado por casualidad, ya que yo lo he usado para navegar en objetos para mostrar de forma personalizada un `var_dump` o `var_export` no se si lo recuerdes que hace un año atras estuve investigando sobre reflection.